# How to print a double data type in C

Tags: c, floating-point

Why in C, when I print a double type variable with %f it shows 8.000000… but that is not the  desire result . i want a result like 8.5000 how can i achieve this?

```
 int main(){
     int i, j;
      double k;
      i=8; j=9;
      k = (i+j)/2;
      printf("%f", k);
    }
```

Comment: int divided by int results in (rounded)  int

Comment: Try `k = (i+j)/2;` ==> `k = (i+j)/2.0;`

Comment: @MichaelButscher: "rounded" ==> "truncated"

Comment: @pmg Right, of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the format specifier, rather with the arithmatic operation.

By saying

```
 k = (i+j)/2;
```

where, `i` and `j`  and `2` - all are `int`s, you're doing integer division, and then, storing the result in a `double`. For integer division,

> [..] When integers are divided, the result of the `/` operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded [...]

which is commonly known as "truncation towards zero". To avoid that from happenning, you need to enforce floating point arithmetic, by forcing or casting one of the operands to `double` (or `float`). Something like

```
k = ((double)i+j)/2;
```

or,

```
k = (i+j)/2.0;  //2.0 is of type double
```

The point here is, if, in the operation, one of the operands is of the higher rank (`double` or `float` is higher ranked that `int`), all the operands will first be converted to the higher rank, and then the operation will be performed and the result will be of the type of the higher ranked type.

Comment: thanks so much for your explanation i got it now

Answer (score 0):

Since i and j are `int` the result is cast first to `int`. This looses precision. Explicitly cast to double `k = (double)(i+j)/2`

Comment: I would say the result is an integer right away as only integer arithmetic will be performed. There is no cast involved at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Comments are right. To better understand that: A C expression is evaluated in 'one chunk'. The right side of your assignment `(i+j)/2` is a complete expression. Since it does only includes integer values, the arithmetic chosen will also be of integer type, (which leads to truncation of the result), creating temporary integer value (invisible to you), which is then assigned to a `double`.

You need to make at least one of the values in your expression a `double` (or `float`), then the compiler will promote all the arithmetic to floating point and the temporary value will also be of float type.

If you don't have a constant in your expression, you can also use casts:

```
((float)i+J)/2
```

It does not matter which of the 3 items get the cast, just one is enough.

Comment: `creating temporary integer value (invisible to you), which is then assigned to a double ---> truncation.` is that so?

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh AFAIK yes.

Comment: I dont think so. If you try to mean that the result of integer division tends to truncate the result - I agree. But storing an integer in a double results in truncation - can you cite some source of that?

Comment: Well, if I look at a disassembly, the arithmetic is performed using integer addition and right shift. The assigment into the double is preceded by cvtsi2sd (conversion from int to float) on an x86-64 processor. So, yes I'd say the intermediate value, which is kept in a gp-register, is indeed a temporary integer. The truncation already happens when the arithmetic is performed.

Comment: Ah, I see our misunderstanding. Bad wording on my side, sorry. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: No problem, we're here to help each other to rule out the confusions and increase the overall quality, cheers!!